# How to achieve iOS like smooth page transition animation in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I was checking out the app The History of Everything because I am learning about coding Flutter apps. But then I noticed the page transition animation in the app is way smoother than my own application which is also made with Flutter. You can see the comparison below:

[image: My App]

^ You can see that in my app, when I am doing a swipe gesture and release haft way, it immediately reset to 0 without any transitions.

[image: The History of Everything]

^ You can see that in The History of Everything, when I am doing a swipe gesture and release haft way, it does a smooth transition back to 0.

I checked their source code on GitHub (https://github.com/2d-inc/HistoryOfEverything) and it's pushing the route the same way I did, using `MaterialPageRoute`. I am already building my app on on my phone using release mode so it shouldn't be performance related.

Here is how I push to a new route:

```dart
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) {
      return MessageScreen(conversation: _conversation);
    },
  ),
);
```

Here is my Flutter doctor output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Mac OS X 10.14.4 18E226, locale en-HK)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.2.1)
    ✗ Verify that all connected devices have been paired with this computer in
      Xcode.
      If all devices have been paired, libimobiledevice and ideviceinstaller may
      require updating.
      To update with Brew, run:
        brew update
        brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
        brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies usbmuxd
        brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
        brew unlink usbmuxd
        brew link usbmuxd
        brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
        brew install ideviceinstaller
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.33.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

What am I missing here that makes the difference?

Comment: are you executing your app in release mode too?

Comment: @Rubens Melo Yes I am building it using `flutter run --release`

Comment: how did you share gifs in question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After upgrading to Flutter 1.5 it's now having the same page transition.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have a slide transition like `iOS`, you use:

```dart
CupertinoPageRoute. 
Navigator.push(
    context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen2()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [PageView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) and encapsulate your page and its contents as children to it.